# Alternative solution for JSON.NET attributes

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

Currently in my model classes I have some JSON.NET attributes like

```
public class MyModel
{
     [JsonProperty("_anothername")]
     [JsonConverter(typeof(MyCustomConverter))]
     public string Name { get; set; }     
}
```

Is there any alternative solution that won't "pollute" my model class? The contract resolver probably works but it's too heavy. I want something like this:

```
var contract = new JsonContract<MyModel>();
contract.Property(m => m.Name)
        .HasAlias("_anothername")
        .HasConverter<MyCustomConverter>();
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myModelInstance, contract);
```

Ideally the model classes knew nothing about JSON.NET, and the project should not have JSON.NET reference.

EDIT: Maybe some other JSON library works, but I don't want to involve another library because JSON.NET is widely used in this project.

UPDATE: It seems that contract resolver is the standard way to do this, I found [this library](https://github.com/ErikSchierboom/JsonDotNetCustomContractResolvers) is close to my expectation. I'll try to write my own implementation later.

Comment: `The contract resolver probably works but it's too heavy. I want something like this` And how do you think to achieve this? If there were something built-in you would already have used it.